# Jackson is ignoring all fields from parent

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I have 2 classes `Parent` and a `Child`.

## Parent

```
public abstract class Parent implements Serializable{
    protected String id;
    protected String deletedAt;
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getDeletedAt() {
        return deletedAt;
    }
    public void setDeletedAt(String deletedAt) {
        this.deletedAt = deletedAt;
    }
}
```

## Child

```
public class Child extends Parent{
    private String name;
    public String getName(){
    ...
}
```

when i load the Child and try to go like this :

```
Child c = getChildFromDb();
c.getId();
```

and this is my jackson config:

## JacksonConfig

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder;

@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = builder.createXmlMapper(false).build();
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS, false);
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

the ID is null but the Name is there. What i am doing wrong ?

Comment: what is the input ?

Comment: @reos find any child or all the childs

Comment: What is the json/xml that you're parsing ?

Comment: Cursor<Treatment> cursor= coreDB.table(tableName).run(connectionFactory.createConnection(),Treatment.class);
        List<Treatment> result=cursor.toList();
        
        for(Treatment t:result){
         System.out.println("id = "+t.getId());
         System.out.println("name = "+t.getName());
        }
        return result;

id is always null but there is a name in the console
same in the result json

Comment: 100% sure its not about what i am parsing, it's about the jackson mapping to object it can't set the id on the parent
if i added this to the child
@override
public void setId(String id){
this.id=id;}
it works but then i need to add like 20 methods and the inheretane concept is lost

Comment: hmmm this is weird, I've made a test and this works properly. Are your properties public ?

Comment: I tried public protected and default nothing worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be a problem with the DB Driver of 'rethink' for some reason rethink DB driver ignored the fields of the parent class and this caused that those fields were never stored in the DB so they were never retrieved.
Changed the DB with its driver to MongoDB and it works perfectly now.